# Call a C# method with DTO as entered parameter in python

Tags: python, python.net

I am using pythonnet and import .Net dll without any problem, but I faced with new problem when I want to call a C# method with `DTO` as entered parameter not primitive type such as `string`,`int`,`bool` and etc.

For Example (C# .Net), Suppose we have this below class in .Net dll:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

above method named `Sum` can be called in Pythonnet like a charm, but suppose I have bellow code and method named `Sum` which get `DTO` as parameter:

```
public class Dto
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}
public class Class2
{
    public static int Sum(Dto dto)
    {
        return dto.Prop1 + dto.Prop2;
    } 
}
```

I am trying to initiate `Dto` and call `Sum` like below but exception happened:

```
import clr
from collections import namedtuple 
assembly = clr.AddReference('ContrastEnhancement')
assembly = clr.AddReference('SimpleITKCSharpManaged')

clr.AddReference('SimpleITKCSharpManaged')
clr.AddReference('ContrastEnhancement')

from ContrastEnhancement import Class1 
# a= Class1.Sum1(2,7)
x=2
y=7
SomeClass = namedtuple('dto', ['Prop1','Prop2'])
myobject = SomeClass(x,y)
a= Class1.Sum(myobject)
print(a)
```

below exception happening:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError
> No method matches given arguments for Class1.Sum: (<class '**main**.dto'>)
> File "/home/davood/Sitk-Linux/app.py", line 91, in 
> a= Class1.Sum(myobject)

Comment: Why can't you instantiate `Dto` as you do `SomeClass`?

Comment: As you can see I insatiate `Dto` and `myobject` have it's value as I want but while I call Sum by passing `myobject` I get that exception.

Comment: @DavoodAkbarikia no, you are not instantiating `Dto`, you are creating a different class and passing its instance. Instead you must `from ... import Class1, Dto` then `myobject = Dto()`. C# is a strictly typed language, so you can't just substitute classes, unless you use `dynamic`.

Comment: @LOST, It works like a charm, Thank you for your solution, I am newbie and can't find any sample through the internet. You can add your comment as answer and I will accept it.